# Linux script with curl to check webservice status

Tags: web-services, shell, unix, curl, wget

I have a license validation webservice provided at http://localhost/testing/validateLicence

I want to write a shell script in such way that I have to pass license key with webservice call . If webservice returns 200 OK then further steps in shell script are executed otherwise execution will be terminated

Please help me in calling web service and comparing http response code in if/else block according to my requirement

Comment: IMHO your license check needs to verify the identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this question:

https://superuser.com/questions/272265/getting-curl-to-output-http-status-code

You should be able tou se something like this (from the second answer there) in a script for your logic:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -I -w "%{http_code}" http://www.example.org/
```

Remove the -I if your web service doesn't like HEAD requests.